# How Optimize this HTTP Request Method for Dispose Freezes in UI Thread?

Tags: flutter, dart, base64, freeze, dio

When i run this method, in flutter, for example when I `onTap` in gesture detector flutter freezes 2 times, when `get` method invoke (I'm think there because of Dio json converter, maybe, idk), and when `base64Decode` method invoke

On the flutter web when `get` method invoke, flutter frizzed at all (`onSendProgress` not work to at this time too) and after this application in chrome crash with code 5, after minute, or two maybe -_-

`context` is not `BuildContext`

`httpClient` is Dio HTTP client

`transformOf` check is request result is error, and if yes, transform request result to my flutter custom exceptions, and after throw it, else return request result.

Request result size is **20-50mb**

```dart
Future<Uint8List> readBookFile(Identificator groupId, Identificator bookId) async {
  final result = await context.httpClient.get(
    '/book/file',
    queryParameters: {
      'groupId': groupId.toString(),
      'bookId': bookId.toString(),
    },
  ).transformOf(context);

  return base64Decode(result['bookBytes']);
}
```

How optimise this code for dispose freezes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fix this I create 2 parse and 2 compute functions

```dart
Uint8List parseBase64(String base64) {
  return base64Decode(base64);
}

Future<Uint8List> parseBase64Compute(String base64) {
  return compute<String, Uint8List>(parseBase64, base64.trim());
}

Map<String, dynamic> parseJson(String json) {
  return jsonDecode(json);
}

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> parseJsonCompute(String base64) {
  return compute<String, Map<String, dynamic>>(parseJson, base64);
}
```

After I'm create simple dio transformer for json

```dart
class JsonTransformer extends DefaultTransformer {
  JsonTransformer() : super(jsonDecodeCallback: parseJsonCompute);
}
```

And apply this

```dart
httpClient.transformer = JsonTransformer();
```

And refactored function is

```dart
Future<Uint8List> readBookFile(Identificator groupId, Identificator bookId) async {
  final result = await context.httpClient.get(
    '/book/file',
    queryParameters: {
      'groupId': groupId.toString(),
      'bookId': bookId.toString(),
    },
  ).transformOf(context);

  return parseBase64Compute(result['bookBytes']);;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Flutter apps do all of their work on a single UI thread. If you try to perform expensive computation inside that UI thread your app's UI gets freeze.

**Problem**

In your case `base64Decode(result['bookBytes']);` is a very expensive computation. (because it decode large data set (20-50mb))

**Solution**

You can solve this by using a **separate Isolate** for running the above expensive task. (see below code)

1. create a method called `parseBookBytes()` put the expensive `baseDecode64()` task into it.
2. Using compute() function execute `parseBookBytes()` in a separate isolate.

```
// A function that converts a result into a Uint8List.
Uint8List parseBookBytes(var bookBytes) {
  return base64Decode(bookBytes);
}

Future<Uint8List> readBookFile(Identificator groupId, Identificator bookId) async {
  final result = await context.httpClient.get(
    '/book/file',
    queryParameters: {
      'groupId': groupId.toString(),
      'bookId': bookId.toString(),
    },
  ).transformOf(context);

  return compute(parseBookBytes, result['bookBytes']);   //run on a separate isolate using compute() function
}
```

---

**Resources**

1. [Link 1](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing)
2. [Link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AxWC49ZMzs)
3. [Link 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8jGSkACneE)

Comment: Thanks. So helpful. But for fix dio json convert freezes I do more. [I written is there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70313677/10387571)